# is function $f(x,y)=\sin\frac{\pi}{1-x^2-y^2}$ uniformly continuous in $x^2+y^2<1$?

Tags: analysis

Is the function $f(x,y)=\sin\frac{\pi}{1-x^2-y^2}$  uniformly continuous in  $x^2+y^2<1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1. Note that $h(x):=\sin\frac{\pi}{1-x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous in $(-1,1)$ because it cannot be extended continuously to $[-1,1]$.

Hint 2. For $n\geq 1$, let
$$P_n:=\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2n+1/2}},0\right)\quad ,\quad
Q_n:=\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2n-1/2}},0\right)$$
then $|P_n|<1$ and $|Q_n|<1$, $|P_n-Q_n|\to 0$, but $f(P_n)-f(Q_n)=1-(-1)=2\not\to 0$.

Comment: I didn't understand, why h(x) is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Bakhytbek See my second hint. Is it clear now?